# Permission issue inside docker on WSL

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try to start jenkins inside docker inside WSL I get a permission issue.

```
⇒  sudo docker run --name jenkins_3 -p 8081:8080 -p 50001:50000 -e JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/c/exemple_dir" jenkins  

/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh: line 23: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war 
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Jenkins has failed to create a temporary file in /tmp 
        at Main.extractFromJar(Main.java:397)
        at Main._main(Main.java:230)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
        at Main.extractFromJar(Main.java:394)
```

My /tmp folder have all the permission

```
⇒  ls -ald /tmp     
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 512 Jun 13 13:45 /tmp
```

./bin permissions :

```
⇒  ls -ald /usr/local/bin 
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 Jun  4 16:07 bin
```

Comment: Try giving another value to `java.io.tmpdir`, something like `/tmp`?

Comment: Hello @Panki, 
Same error with : -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp